# The server successfully processed the request but failed to return the data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, post

The API executes on the insomnia Tool successfully, and responds successfully. However, On My Browser it does not respond with successful status, instead it shows status as 204 and (cancelled) also there is no error message on the console. The test data is also successfully added in the database despite the 204 & cancelled status.  The server is running on the local host. The problem is that despite this, I am not receiving the intended response "statusCode": 200,
"message": "User added Successfully"

Appreciate any assistance with this! Thank you!

[image] [image]

**Client Side API call**

```
         import axios from "axios";
            
                 let addUser = () => {
                        axios
                          .post(`http://localhost:3000/users/signup`, {
                            firstName: "testFirstName",
                            lastName: "testLastName",
                            email: "testEmail@gmail.com",
                            password: "testPassword",
                          })
                          .then((res) => {
                            console.log(res);
                            console.log(res.data);**
                          })
                          .catch((e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                          });
                      };
return (
    <form>
    ... 
         <button type="submit" onClick={addUser}>submit</button>
    ...
    </form>
);
```

**Server Side**

```
const express = require("express");
const userRouter = express.Router();
const { User } = require("../../models");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

userRouter.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  // get req body

  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

  //validate incoming request

  try {
    const user = User.build({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password,
    });
    await user.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({
      statusCode: 400,
      message: "validation failed",
      details: e.errors[0].message,
    });

    return;
  }

  //encrypt the password with bcrypt

  const saltRounds = 10;
  try {
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);

    // update database
    let user = await User.create({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password: hash,
    });

    // respond to the request

    res.status(200).json({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: "User added Succcessfully",
      data: user,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
      statusCode: 500,
      message: "Internal Server Error",
      details: e.errors[0].message,
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

In My (nodeJS) main Server Index.JS file I have enabled All CORS Requests

```
...

    const cors = require("cors");
    
    app.use(cors());
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.listen(3000, async () => {
      console.log("http://localhost:3000/");
      try {
        await db.sequelize.sync({ alter: true });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Database not connected due to error ${e}`);
      }
    });
    
    app.use("/users", userRouter); // Mount the router as middleware at path /user
    
    
    app.use((req, res) => {
      res.status(404).json({
        msg: " file not found",
      });
    });

...
```

Comment: what do you send in header in insomnia ? you should do it the same in the code

Comment: Why do you have a Return ? return should not be capitalized

Comment: @A.Zaveri can you share the UI codes that call the `addUser`

Comment: @Andy addUser is called by the onClick event <button type="submit" onClick={addUser}>submit</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

The reason is, the elements submits the form on the click event interrupting the API call. Hence the action causes a load to be interrupted. This can happen when a new navigation interrupts an existing one.

To prevent request from being cancelled, JavaScript `event.preventDefault()`; has to be called:

Please read the below article that helped me solve this, hope this helps you too!

https://newbedev.com/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 1):

Try change your button markup into

```
 <button type="button" onClick={() => addUser()}>submit</button>
```

Update:

To add more context into the answer above, the reason the request gets canceled is due the codes has a `<form>` that wraps around the `<button type='submit'>`. Click a submit button would submit the `form` and that would cancel out the request triggered by click event of the submit button.

There's few ways to fix this:

1. By changing the button to regular `type="button"` (so that it doesn't submit the form).
2. add `event.preventDefault();` to the `onClick` event handler, so that the click event doesn't bubble up to submit the form.
3. Remove the `<form>` wrapper entirely since it's not really being used in this case.
4. Add an `onsubmit` event handler for the `form` and move the `axios` codes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Because it says cancelled, it is probably a cors issue. You can hover the mouse on "cancelled" and a tooltip will show up why.

You probably needed to configure cors a bit more.

```js
app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
  }
));
```